# How to ignore a noise value in real time?

Tags: python, noise

I'm trying to make an alarm program that goes green when above 4.27v, goes red when below -2.56v, and no light in between these values. I have been supplied with a dataset from which I'm supposed to continuously read and make the alarm goes off accordingly. But there are some noise in the data when it's in the high values and I'm supposed to ignore these noise so the alarm doesn't flicker.

For example, if the reading goes `4.30 > 4.40 > 4.20 > 4.50 > ...` I have to ignore the `4.20` and the alarm have to keep being green, not turn off for 1 second then turn on again.

This is what I have tried, but it still flickers:

```
high_alarm = 4.27
low_alarm = -2.56
Q = 0.009765625

prev1 = 0
prev2 = 0

for i in range(120):
    volt_bit = my_daq.next_reading()
    volts = volt_bit * Q - 5
        
    prev2 = prev1
    prev1 = volts
        
    if volts > high_alarm:
        # green light
        bstick.set_color(index=6, name="green")
    elif volts <= high_alarm and volts >= low_alarm:
        if prev2 > prev1 and volts > prev1:
            continue
        lights_off()
    elif volts < low_alarm:
        # red light
        bstick.set_color(index=3, name="red")
```

I also have the idea to compare both previous and next data to the current value, but that's not possible because I have to do it in real time, so I'm not supposed to know future readings, only current & previous ones.

Here's a sample dataset of the flickering high values if anyone wanna try:

```
[991,
978,
962,
965,
959,
964,
945, # flickered here
956,
960,
959,
953]
```

Comment: What about a sliding average with a large window?

Answer (score 1):

The scientific approach to solving this problem would be something like [this](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/guha16.pdf) (Robust Random Cut Forest Based Anomaly Detection On Data Streams).
Based on the anomaly score, you could either control the alarm directly or train a neural network to generate a control signal for the alarm.